# Error: React Hook "useLogout" cannot be called inside a callback. Apollo

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I'm not sure what is this error about and how to fix it?

Code:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Layout, Loading, LangContext } from '@frontend'
import { gql, useMutation } from '@apollo/client'

const LogoutMutation = gql`
  mutation LogoutMutation {
    logout
  }
`

const Logout = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [useLogout] = useMutation<{ logout: boolean }>(LogoutMutation)

  useEffect(() => {
    useLogout().then(({ data }) => {
      if (data?.logout === true) window.location.href = '/'
    })
  }, [useLogout])

  return null
}

export default Logout
```

Error:

> 16:5  error  React Hook "useLogout" cannot be called inside a
>   callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or
>   a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Answer (score 4):

React aslo recognize function name begin with 'use' as custom hook, so i need to change `useLogout => doLogout`